Connecting 12V fan and LED light to 220V
I want to connect a 12V fan with a fan controller and a 12V LED light to a 220V outlet. How should the circuit diagram look, and what components do you recommend?

I recommend an appropriately sized 12V wall wart with the loads connected in parallel. At least 2x the sum total of the nameplate currents of everything connected to it should be worry-free.

Thank you! If understood correctly, I only need to connect parallel wires from the power jack to on/off switch, led and fan controller. And parallel wires from the switch to led and fan controller?

Better draw a diagram of what you're envisioning.

I have updated my post

You can buy off-the-shelf 12V power supplies.  So that's the component I would recommend.


Quick diagram shown, hope it helps.
